# RuntimeError: Model class mainpage_authentication.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django

Before applying models to my project everything was okay. But when I just applied them, the system crushed. I'm a freshmen learning Django, so will be grateful for an explanation, and a solution, if possible.

My code:

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import User


admin.site.register(User)
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AuthenticationPageConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'mainpage_authentication'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import User


class AuthenticationLoginForm(forms.Form):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mainpage_authentication',
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import views
from mainpage_authentication.forms import AuthenticationLoginForm


class MainPageView(views.View):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'mainpage.html')


class AuthenticationLoginPageView(views.View):
    def get(self, request):
        form: AuthenticationLoginForm = AuthenticationLoginForm()
        return render(request, 'authentication-page.html', {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
from mainpage_authentication.models import User
```

instead of

```
from .models import User
```

Basically use an absolute import instead of a relative import for that model.

Comment: Were you able to get it working?

Comment: nothing changed, unfortunately, the same issue

Comment: please tag me so that i get a notification. 

Can you add the exact error you are getting now?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9544403/arun-t here is the exact error: RuntimeError: Model class mainpage_authentication.models.User doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.